# tintColor not updating to default in Theme

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom icon (.png image) as a barbutton and I'm going to be using a Theme.swift file to set asset colors/background color for 1 particular view controller but for some reason the tint color is not updating.

It's currently the dark grey color used when it was added to my Assets folder, but should show up as a green color as per my Theme.swift. Does anyone know of a reason why this might not be updating to the new default color of green:

[image]

In the viewDidLoad of the viewcontroller I'm looking to theme, I have added

```
Theme.current.apply()
```

And this is my Theme.swift file with a default green color:

```
import UIKit

enum Theme: Int {
    //1
    case `default`, dark, graphical

    //2
    private enum Keys {
        static let selectedTheme = "SelectedTheme"
    }

    //3
    static var current: Theme {
        let storedTheme = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: Keys.selectedTheme)
        return Theme(rawValue: storedTheme) ?? .default
    }

    var mainColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .default:
            print("/default")
            return UIColor(red: 87.0/255.0, green: 188.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case .dark:
            return UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 115.0/255.0, blue: 50.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case .graphical:
            return UIColor(red: 10.0/255.0, green: 10.0/255.0, blue: 10.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }


func apply() {

    //2
    UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.tintColor = mainColor
}
}
```

/default even prints in my console, but the color does not update.

Answer (score 0):

Here, problem with image `renderingMode`. If you want to apply `tintColor` on image you have to use image rendering mode as `alwaysTemplate`.

Image rendering mode can be set using two methods.

**Programmatically**

```
if let myImage = UIImage(named: "myImage") {
    let tintableImage = myImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView.image = tintableImage
}
```

**From Asset**

[image]

Comment: Hey, I just check my asset and its showing render: default - https://imgur.com/a/9qKHsum

Comment: Change to `alwaysTemplate `

Comment: Oh! I misread your post. Ok now its Template image but still not working in simulator. Anything else I can look at?

Comment: hmm.. Try to apply static `tintColor` from storyboard for now. It's easy to debug.

Comment: @bhealth Your `Theme` class working for me.. As your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `NavigationBar tint color`

Sample code for change navigation bar tint color

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.purple //your selected color
```

Sample for your apply method please check it

```
func apply() {

    UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.tintColor = mainColor

    // change navigation bar tint colour
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = mainColor // or your selected color

}
```

Comment: The NavigationBar tint color also doesn't change with apply method as you suggested

Comment: @Moritz I agree with you but this code is just for this particular answer, you are not consider for all projects and all scenario, In this code "`bhealth`" will save selected theme in `UserDefault` thats why I wrote `UserDefault` code, But I have remove `UserDefault` code in my answer